# AWS Route 53 integration of Private cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cloud

We have our app instances on enterprise private cloud where we load balance with in the data center using Haproxy, we would like to use AWS Route53 to achieve GEO Proximity and direct traffic to it's closest Data center.

Is there any way we can register an external domain and make it talk to our Private haproxy servers based up on health checks and routing policy? any inputs are welcome.

Thanks and Regards
Raj

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this, but the solution may be against your design to keep your servers private.

You will need to create proxy load balancers (internet facing) in each region. Add your existing servers to the load balancer. Add each of these load balancers in the Route 53 public hosted zone entry for geo load balancing.

I would recommend adding a security layer for all inbound requests as your private cloud is now open to public with this approach.

Comment: Thanks Yesh, I will give a try all our apps are listening on 443, We configured load balancer servers based up on Haproxy is already in place and ready to listen on 443 to the internet. I can give a try on adding these load balancer servers in the route 53 public hosted zones. Will update you on this, Thanks again for responding